# How can I put end Icon in TreeView Material UI in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm using React `TreeItem` material UI. I am using the custom `StyledTreeItem` function from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ui4dx). The thign I want is icon at the end of label. I want to use `endIcon` but it is not working.

Here is the code which I have done so far:
`<StyledTreeItem endIcon={ArrowDropDownIcon}></StyledTreeItem>;`

What I want to do is to use SVG icon in `endIcon` like this:
`<StyledTreeItem endIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}></StyledTreeItem>;`

The function which I'm using has been taken from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ui4dx).

But somehow it is not working.

Is this achievable? How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

endIcon property doesn't place the icon at the end of label but it places the icon beside the last child of the node.
[TreeItem API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFHrA.png)

However, if you need your icon to be placed at the end of label, it can be achieved with css.